# Will changing the setting on my Crock Pot reset the timer?

Tags: equipment, slow-cooking, crockpot

If I have a [Crock Pot "Smart Pot"](http://www.samsclub.com/sams/shop/product.jsp?productId=prod2610262&navAction=) set to "High" (or 4 hours) and then I change the setting to "Low" or 10 hours, does the time start over or will it just cook for 10 hours from the time I changed it?

For instance, if I put the crock pot on high at noon, it will turn off at 4 PM; say I change it to low at 2 PM - will the slow cooker turn off at midnight (10 hours later) or just cook on low until 4 PM?

Comment: The answer might be a little too specific to that product.

Comment: I'm *kind of* inclined to let this one be, because the brand is in fact a Crock Pot, which is pretty much the most popular brand there is, and I have to assume that all of their models work similarly. So this is probably relevant to anyone who owns any Crock Pot, and there are a whole lot of 'em. That said, the manual would be a better place to look for the answer than the internet...

Answer (score 1):

From experience cooking chili in Crock-Pot brand slow cookers, each time you change the setting (at least from high to low or vice versa), it resets the timer. Also, of course, so does high->off->high.

So, (at least my Crock-Pots) would cook on low until midnight in your example.

Well, unless the power went out for three seconds. (It'd be off after the power blip.)

Personally, I've switched to non-"programmable" slow cookers.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are, unless your cooker has a documented feature that explicitly remembers its timer state, it is going to reset. Most of these devices are pretty simple, electronically, and you would probably know it if yours was capable of maintainng state.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Davy8.  But being a programmer, I'd have to guess that the time starts over when you change the setting